# Cannot boot into Live CD (12.10), Live USB (14.04), or Boot-Repair USB

Tags: boot, grub2, live-usb, live-cd, sata

I am trying to boot into Ubuntu on removable media in an attempt to fix my bootloader for a Ubuntu 12.10 install on an HDD. However, it seems that I'm not able to boot into any of the media I've tried. Here's what happens

From 12.10 Live CD:
Get past purple screen with the small man at the bottom. Then, black screen with blinking cursor. After about 15 seconds, the cursor stops blinking. No activity light on the DVD drive. I have to do a hard reset.

From 14.04 USB and Boot-Repair USB:
After selecting to boot from USB, I see the UnetBootin screen with various options. Regardless of choice, I then get a resized version of the same screen, with the UnetBootin options box, blinking cursor underneath, which stops after a few seconds. Then I hard reset because nothing happens.

What have I tried:

From 12.10 CD
Hold shift to access boot options. I've tried nomodeset, same exact results.

From USB devices:
Not much, since I can't really do anything once it freezes.
All media work on my laptop to boot.

Any advice on what to try next? Or why this is happening? I've got a 12.10 install on my HDD that I haven't booted into in quite some time. I've for windows 7 on my SSD (primary OS). I wanted to get back into Linux but this is giving me trouble :(

Some additional info: I can boot to a Windows 7 recovery disc DVD, and (more importantly) I can boot to a linux-based OCZ SSD utility that is on a USB.

SOLUTION: Here's how I ended up getting it to work: I have an Asrock Z77 Extreme4 mobo, which has both intel SATA ports and SATA ports run by an Asrock driver. The CD drive was plugged into the Asrock SATA ports, and this was causing some kind of hang because communication through that port is unsupported. I simply unplugged it from the Asrock port and into an Intel port and voila! All of my various USB memory sticks and the CD drive were able to boot, and I was able to boot into Boot-Repair to repair the bootloader of my Ubuntu 12.10 install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I ended up getting it to work: gyropyge's comment about the CD drive not working gave me pause. I have an Asrock Z77 Extreme4 mobo, which has both intel SATA ports and SATA ports run by an Asrock driver. The CD drive was plugged into the Asrock SATA ports, and this was causing some kind of hang because communication through that port is unsupported. I simply unplugged it from the Asrock port and into an Intel port and voila! All of my various USB memory sticks and the CD drive started to work, and I was able to boot into Boot-Repair to repair the bootloader of my Ubuntu 12.10 install.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain, but it seems likely your cd/dvd (optical) drive isn't working.  I recommend you borrow an external USB model from a friend, or even buy one.  They only cost about $16 these days.  I just looked [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002782LTG) up on amazon at that price which I purchased last year.  It works fine.  They can be very handy in service work, and if your internal optical drive has failed, this could save money over the cost of having the internal one replaced.

Personally I run into this problem so often I've made a self-booting boot-repair flashdrive, and I was pleased to find it actually boots faster than it would off of CD.  That could be an alternative for you, if you have access to a pc onto which you can download the ISO image of the boot media you wish to boot to and then use [unetbootin](https://launchpad.net/unetbootin) to write that image to a usb flash drive.

Comment: I can't boot from USB either though. That's the problem. Some additional info: I can boot to a Windows 7 recovery disc DVD, and (more importantly) I can boot to an linux OCZ utility on a USB. It seems Ubuntu is the common denominator. Is it worth trying to boot from a Live-USB an older version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Here's how I ended up getting it to work: your comment about the CD drive not working gave me pause. I have an Asrock Z77 Extreme4 mobo, which has both intel SATA ports and SATA ports run by an Asrock driver. The CD drive was plugged into the Asrock SATA ports, and this was causing some kind of hang because communication through that port is unsupported. I simply unplugged it from the Asrock port and into an Intel port and voila! All of my various USB memory sticks and the CD drive started to work, and I was able to boot into Boot-Repair to repair the bootloader of my Ubuntu 12.10 install.

Answer (score 0):

First please remake a bootable usb stick with unetbootin or imagewrite and try using another iso (ie the 32 bit version).
If that fails you can try using http://www.plop.at/en/bootmanagers.html as a boot manager (make a usb or a cd with it) to boot a usb from it? Also if the keyboard does not work inside the manager try:

1. search you bios/cmos configuration for support for usb keyboards
2. using an old PS/2 keyboard.

Also what i believe is the cause of the usb not booting is that the utility you use is either out of date or that the uuid of the usb is not computed properly for some reason (this has happened to me some times). Lastly take care that you are not booting from usb3 as many motherboards even if they have onboard usb3, do not support booting from them

BTW: you can set the nomodeset option by editing the various .cfg files in your usb with notepad

Comment: I can boot to a Windows 7 recovery disc DVD, and (more importantly) I can boot to a linux-based OCZ SSD utility that is on a USB. But not Ubuntu distros it seems. I will give your suggestion a try. Thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem, write back if it doesn't work out.